# Add data in query which isn't in type

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

I'm working on a little personal project which export data from Rest API and expose them via Graphql.

I got my type :

```
type Team{
    id: ID,
    name: String,
    code: String
}
```

and the query configured like :

```
type Query {
  teams(id: ID, name: String, code: Int): [Team]
}

Query: {
  teams: (_, filters) => footballService.getTeams(filters),
}
```

filters contains all the arguments passed during the call like `teams(id: 100)`

My problem is that if a want a list of teams from the API, i need to pass the competition ID. So is there a way to do a call like `teams(id: 100, competitionId:200)` without adding `competitionID` in my Team type

Comment: It's not totally clear what you're asking here. You can add any argument to the `teams` field that you want. The fact that you have arguments named `id`, `name` and `code` and another type has fields with those same names is irrelevant.

Comment: @DanielRearden Yes it was hard for me to explain. I want to pass an argument that are not on the type. Like said in my exemple i want to make a call like `teams(id: 100, competitionId:200)` but without adding `competitionID` in any type

Comment: Can you explain why? Are you talking about database schema or actual graphql schema?

Comment: @realAlexBarge I'm talking about graphql schemas, like explained it get my data from an api and the api models aren't the same that mine. To get team list from the api i need to past competition id so basicaly i want to pass a competition id

Comment: But why don't you just add the competitionId? The attributes can be optional and you can just not provide it if you dont want it. E.g.   teams(id: ID, name: String, code: Int, competitionId: Int): [Team]

Comment: @realAlexBarge Cause in the returned data this field will always be `null` it serves just to get the good teams

Comment: Again, adding the argument to `teams` does not mean you have to modify the `Team` type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameters you are defining for your teams query do not have to be the same as your Team type attributes. This is possible:

```
type Team {
    id: ID,
    name: String,
    code: String
}

type Query {
  teams(id: ID, name: String, code: Int, competitionId: Int): [Team]
}

Query: {
  teams: (_, filters) => footballService.getTeams(filters),
}
```

Usually you will have something like this for pagination for example without those fields being part of the model type:

```
type Query {
  teams(
    filter: String
    skip: Int
    first: Int
    orderBy: String
  ): [User!]!
```

You need to make sure however that your resolver (e.g. getTeams) properly handles those parameters.